# Calling images from database produce empty spaces in html

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I've called some images from the database and displayed it on html. The problem is why is there 2 empty spaces among the images? Im using bootstrap 3.3.7. I've cleared cached and refreshed multiple times but still the same.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <?php
            include('dbcon.php');

            $state="Johor";
            $query = "SELECT event_image from blast_events where event_state='$state'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            if($result){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo ' <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
                    <img src="images/'.$row["event_image"].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
                </div>';
            }
            }
            ?>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the source HTML look like? Might give you an idea

Comment: Is there a total of 7 images? or a total of 9 images? and like what @CertainPerformance said, we need to see the output HTML. 
My guess is that you have 7 images, some of them have a different dimension, width, height, or aspect ration.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid there's only 7

Comment: another thing would be the height. If even one isn't the same size as all of the others, then you'll get blank spaces; it happened to me once. Took me a while to find it too.

Comment: Then, it's your CSS styling and spacing. There is extra padding/margin that causes one of the images to be pushed to the right. It couldn't fit the space.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yeah you're right. i adjusted the heights and it worked. silly me. thanks.

Comment: From your browser, Right click -> Inspect -> Edit Style and play with your paddign and margin vlaues. Are you using bootstrap? You can also use CSS Flex Box for the responsive effect.

Comment: as said; CSS is most likely the culprit here. Just as a test, modify your style so that each image receives the same height and width. Say 400px x 200px.

Comment: Ah cool @Grey glad to see that this was solved rather quickly, *cheers!* and welcome.

Comment: @Grey do you want the post to be marked as solved? it's your choice; just curious.

Comment: Silly all of us. I have been there a few times myself. 
@FunkFortyNiner you should promote your comment as an answer so Grey would accept it.

Comment: yeah its solved.thanks for helping. really appreciate :)

Comment: @Grey actually, I rather post an answer for this and a detailed one. Give me a few minutes and I'll write something up and informative. It's a good question and feel it deserves a (good) answer.

Comment: @MohammedJoraid It happened to you also? Did it take you a long time to figure it out? Oh, and I did post an answer below. The question needed to be answer I felt. :-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner yeah, if you noticed my first comment, it's the stuff that I check immediately when a blank space shows instead of an image or HTML block. I can't recall the exact incident when this happened or how long has it been (many moons ago),  but I remember hitting F12 and inspecting the element to see the orange shadow (padding) taking more space than it was supposed to. The other incident was when a designer sent me 10+ images, supposedly the same dimensions, but missed one or two with different height/width.

Answer (score 1):

Put a custom class on that `.row`. Say... `.my-gallery`? And add this to your CSS:

```
.my-gallery {
  display-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

In short, your problem is caused by the fact Bootstrap v3.x.x floats the columns. Your last image in the previous row is one pixel shorter, and the first image in next row gets floated into the extra pixel from 2nd column image. Flexbox fixes this.

An alternative would be to set `.cleafix` class on each 3rd `.col-*-*` item in the list and do it for each responsiveness level, depending on how many items you have per row. A more detailed explanation in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Comment: That's interesting and a good addition to the question I find. I remember having a different issue once when I had to use `clearfix` but can't remember what it was now. What happened to the OP like me once, now *that* I'll always remember *lol!* - Cheers.

Comment: @Funk, It's a common issue with Bootstrap 3 galleries. A typical way to fix it was `.clearfix`, which had `clear:both;` initially but due to some IE bugs they changed it to `.clearfix:after{display:table;height:0;}`. This pretty much broke all existing floating with no downsides. Nowadays flexbox has `97%` browser coverage. Surpasses even `box-shadow`, so that's the way to go. In Bootstrap v4 it's default. ***And*** has the nice benefit one doesn't need to cut all images pixel-perfect coming from design team.

Comment: Thanks for that Andrei, I'll make both a mental and written note about that. Lordie, if this question only existed at the time it happened to me. I think it was about 3-4 years ago. I'm not a CSS guru but I do know how to debug *lol!* Yeah, you gotta love how different browsers have their moods, heh. Cheers. Edit: Yeah, I'll have to upgrade that site with v4 now. I learned a lot today myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

This question is interesting because in all my time here, I've never seen someone have the same problem I had once and it was this:

(My comment)

> another thing would be the height. If even one isn't the same size as all of the others, then you'll get blank spaces; it happened to me once. Took me a while to find it too.

What I meant by my that was this precisely; 
I had the one image somewhere that was 1px difference in height and it threw a lot of things off, with blank spots where there should be images.

It took me a while to figure it out because I had no idea what it was that I was looking for. I looked at the (HTML) source where I found a difference in height. So I set an CSS rule for those images only to a fixed width and height; everything fell back into place.

It took me about an hour; so hopefully I too will save you an hour or possibly more.

Always give an image both an CSS rule of (min. or max.) width and (min. or max.) height as a "Plan B", should something in a text file, or database or in a loop of sort that fetches images is a good idea I feel.

Viewing the HTML source (as stated in comments) is a good debugging tool in its own right. You can see a lot of what's going on in there, as well as the developer's console.

*One extra pixel and the whole house of cards comes down!* heh. Well, I **will** remember that one.

Footnote:

I ended up checking all of the images' sizes and modified them to be the same width and height. I did keep the CSS rule, but commented out and with a descriptive comment inside it `/* this is a comment about the problem/solution */` should this ever happen again.